# How to get YouTube channel attribute Values

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-channels

I would like to retrieve the channel attributes of a channel on YouTube that are available publicly using the YouTube API. 
For example I would like to know the number of views, number of subscribers for the channels below:

1. starPlus
2. GoreJak

The names of the channels are dynamic.
How can this be achieved using the YouTube java API?

I am familiar with getting the video lists and details of a channel using the gdata client library.
For example I can get the video names, descriptions, time of upload etc of the videos in any user channel.
However I am not able to fetch details of the channel itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the channel id from the url. Quite easy!

After that, you need to do a *channel->list* request of the youtube API:

Here's all the data you can get from this request :
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I tried the sample code under the code samples heading, but I am having an issue connecting to YouTube. 
I am running the code YouTubeAnalyticsReport.java from the java code sample section.
The Auth.java requires one to create client_secrets.json file which has values pertaing to the client id and client secret key. 
I do not know what should be the correct value of the following variables.
Authorized JavaScript origins (http://localhost:8080)
Authorized redirect URI (http://localhost:8080/youTube/index.jsp)
Could someone please tell me what these values are.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a FILE cliet_secret.jso
2. COPY the below JSON and replace with your credentials

{
  "installed": {
      "client_id": "PUT YOUT CLIENT ID HERE - U GOT ONE WHERE U CRETAED YOUR Developer ACCOUNT",
      "client_secret": "PUT YOUR CLIENT SECRET HERE"
  }
}

3. Add the servelet.jar file in the class path
4. Add the client_secret.json File to your class path